# LINQ and Entity Framework, get sum of related rows of a non mapped column

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I want to get the sum of applicants that applied to a specific position, this should not be saved as a column.

My model is simple:

We have positions:

- net developer
- java developer

We have applicants:

- Luis
- John
- etc

We have applicants per position

With this column or property  I want to know how many people have applied to each position, depending on the status.
So in my mvc view I want to show something like:

Position       Applied    Accepted  Rejected ... other status

.net developer     5         3         2

java developer     3         2         1

The real problem here is the linq query which I am not very expert.

EDIT:  I think I needed to change where the linq query must be coded, I suppose it should be in the ApplicantPosition class instead of Position, I also changed the types of Position  and Application to be ICollection.

Please see the modified code.

```
 public class Position
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength=3)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int yearsExperienceRequired { get; set; }


    }

    public class Applicant
    {
        public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        public string skypeuser { get; set; }
        public ApplicantImage photo { get; set; }
    }

public class ApplicantPosition
{
    public virtual ICollection<Position> appliedPositions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Applicant> applicants { get; set; }
    public DateTime appliedDate { get; set; }
    public int StatusValue { get; set; }

    public Status Status
    {
        get { return (Status)StatusValue; }
        set { StatusValue = (int)value; }
    }

      [NotMapped]
    public int numberOfApplicantsApplied
    {
        get
        {
            var query = 
                from ap in appliedPositions 
                select new
                {
                    positionName = g.Key.name,
                    peopleApplied = g.Count(x => x.Status == Status.Applied),
                };
            return query.Count(); ---??
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste this into LINQPad as C# Program and run.

```
public enum  Status
{
    Applied, 
    Accepted,
    Rejected
}

public class Position
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Applicant
{
    public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicantPosition
{
    public Position appliedPosition { get; set; }
    public Applicant applicant { get; set; }
    public DateTime appliedDate { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}


void Main()
{
    var p1 = new Position { id = 1, name = ".net developer" };
    var p2 = new Position { id = 2, name = "java developer" };

    var a1 = new Applicant { ApplicantId = 100, name = "Luis" };
    var a2 = new Applicant { ApplicantId = 200, name = "John" };

    var ap1 = new ApplicantPosition { appliedPosition = p1, applicant = a1, Status = Status.Applied };
    var ap2 = new ApplicantPosition { appliedPosition = p1, applicant = a2, Status = Status.Accepted };
    var ap3 = new ApplicantPosition { appliedPosition = p2, applicant = a2, Status = Status.Rejected };

    var db = new[] { ap1, ap2, ap3};

    var query = 
        from ap in db 
        group ap by ap.appliedPosition into g
        select new
        {
            positionName = g.Key.name,
            peopleApplied = g.Count(x => x.Status == Status.Applied),
            peopleAccepted = g.Count(x => x.Status == Status.Accepted),
            peopleRejected = g.Count(x => x.Status == Status.Rejected),
        };

    query.Dump();
}
```

The result will be:

```
positionName     peopleApplied peopleAccepted peopleRejected
.net developer   1             1              0
java developer   0             0              1
```

Comment: thank you, very helpful, but using EF, is it possible to use this same linq query from a Non Mapped column, can you please see this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2010/DEV212, MIN 18:15, thats what I was trying to do.

Comment: Can't get the video, it is stuck on Buffering... Ok. Got the video finally.

Comment: I am almost done, I edited the code again of the query, but the return query.count shows me an error.     The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: If I understand your question right, you can query the database within a getter in Non Mapped column. However, you can't use non-mapped column itself as a part of query. As a workaround you can get all required data from the database in one shot and then execute the query on the in-memory sequence. That will produce same results bvut will use Linq to Object and not Linq to Entities. In that case you can use non-mapped column.

Comment: You probably need to cast Status enum into (int) or vice-versa to let the compiler infer argument type from usage.

Comment: The latest EF CTP includes Enum support.

Answer (score 2):

Use direct SQL with [PIVOT operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx). This is really not a case for Linq query.

Comment: suppose that you only have to know the number of applicants, regardless of the state, my question was the ideal scenario, but if you suppose this, how would you do this with LINQ?

Comment: First of all your result must be a new class - not the mapped one because you cannot fill not mapped column in linq query. You must use projection and projection can be done either to anonymous type or not mapped type = not to your `Position` entity. Once you do projection you can simply assign `Count` of applicants to the property.

Comment: do you have an example of that, I tried doing that way because they explain it on http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2010/DEV212,  18:15, if you see that part of the video, thats what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experiences you can use LinQ or Entity Framework just by mapping your tables in to a DBML to a Entity Framework Model file.
In other way Microsoft gives you a Dynamic LinQ class that you can use it.I think you map all your columns and user Dynamic LinQ class.Good luck

Comment: suppose that you only have to know the number of applicants, regardless of the state, my question was the ideal scenario, but if you suppose this, how would you do this with LINQ?

Comment: aaa...
did you see the SlavaGu answer?I think it helped you enough. need more help?if ya , i can write you more ;-)3